# Where is source code of the binding from javascript to C for Cinnamon? Which C objects / methods can be accessed?

Tags: javascript, applet, cinnamon

My goal was to find out what properties/methods of UI of Cinnamon I can access from `javascript` code. In the javascript code of Cinnamon I see e.g. (`applet.js`):

```
const St = imports.gi.St;
...
this._applet_label = new St.Label({ reactive: true,
                                    track_hover: true,
                                    style_class: 'applet-label'});
```

In the Cinnamon code from https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon I've found `st-label.h` with:

```
struct _StLabel
{
  /*< private >*/
  StWidget parent_instance;

  StLabelPrivate *priv;
};

struct _StLabelClass
{
  StWidgetClass parent_class;
};
```

But I could not find the code for the binding from `_StLabel` to `St.Label`. How do I find all methods, variables from binded `C` UI libraries I can use in `javascript` code?

For `const Tooltips = imports.ui.tooltips;` I see `tooltips.js` in `js/ui` folder. However how `gi.St` is found by `javascript` engine?

In particular I want to change the font of the label (via `style_class` or even better size, color etc. separately via their own objects/properties/methods). I could not find such code in Cinnamon applets sources, I've found font change is commonly made via themes by the user, but I want more fine-grained control.